# Xpath query with multiple conditions in XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, xquery

(Due to sensitivity of the XML data I am working with, I had to remove the data on it. The original size of the XML was 15MB).

Below is the XML that i'm trying to query the count of Funds elements/nodes that have **"|40|" as substring in `FundGroupIDConcat`** attribute and **`PegStatusCurr = 1`**

I tried to evaluate this query and failed to get it running. (I'm running this is VB.NET)

```
(count(.//FundGroups/FundGroup/FundGroups/FundGroup/FundList/Fund[@PegStatusCurr ,""1"")>0)
```

XML:

```
<FR>
    <FundGroups>
        <FundGroup FundGroupID="-1" FundGroupIDConcat="-1|" >
            <FundGroups>
                <FundGroup FundGroupID="100" FundGroupIDConcat="-1|100|">
                    <FundList>
                        <Fund PegStatusCurr="1" PegStatusNew="1">
                            <Name>Account</Name>
                        </Fund>
                    </FundList>
                </FundGroup>
                <FundGroup FundGroupID="7" FundGroupIDConcat="-1|7|">
                    <FundGroups>
                        <FundGroup FundGroupID="40" FundGroupIDConcat="-1|7|40|">
                            <FundGroups>
                                <FundGroup FundGroupID="3240" FundGroupIDConcat="-1|7|40|3240|">
                                    <FundList>
                                        <Fund PegStatusCurr="1" PegStatusNew="1">
                                            <Name>Century One</Name>
                                        </Fund>
                                        <Fund PegStatusCurr="2" PegStatusNew="2">
                                            <Name>Century Two</Name>
                                        </Fund>
                                    </FundList>
                                </FundGroup>
                            </FundGroups>
                        </FundGroup>                        
                    </FundGroups>
                </FundGroup>
            </FundGroups>
        </FundGroup>
    </FundGroups>
</FR>
```

I'm very new to XPath Query and I am having trouble fixing it.

Comment: If this is helpful, Try using http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm to evaluate the Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count(.//FundGroups/FundGroup/FundGroups/FundGroup[contains(@FundGroupIDConcat,'|40|')]/FundList/Fund[@PegStatusCurr = 1])
```

This will give the count of the funds

Answer (score 1):

To get a unique match, use the following expression:

```
.//FundGroups/FundGroup/FundGroups/FundGroup/FundList/Fund[contains(@FundGroupIDConcat,'|40|') and @PegStatusCurr = 1]
```

A `count(...)` expression surrounding that returns `1` elements as result on the sample XML.

One problem that remains are values of `40` without `|` before or after the value.
But you didn't have asked for that, so it may not be a problem at all...

Comment: What if we don't have @FundGroupIDConcat at the <Fund/> level but only at its Parent <FundGroup > as hignlighted above?

Comment: Was able to fig out the answer. Thank you :)